# how can i setup my cable modem to allow me to access two difrrent remote pc

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am using a Technicolor modem with spectrum cable service but was only able to remote into 1 pc, internally and externally. I need to atleast to remote into 2 computers and add 1 security camera externally

Comment: If you're using port forwarding through a home router (whether it is the modem another device), you can only forward a port on a 1:1 basis, meaning that for each port, it can only go to one address - you can't remote to two devices on the same port through the router. You can, however, change the listening port of the service and then forward that port to the second/third device.

Comment: You could just host a VPN on your network and connect to it. Then you can connect to as many devices as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is not NAT,

You can use port translation, e.g.

WAN port 6000 > LAN port 80 for IP 192.168.1.2

WAN port 6001 > LAN port 80 for IP 192.168.1.3

etc..